# sonata admin - get post data

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm learning symfony2 and sonata admin and came across few problems and this is one of them.
I've created an admin class which extends sonata admin and the below wouldn't work for me:

`$this->getForm()->get('page')`

or

`$this->getRequest()->request->get('page')`

I'm trying to pass some hidden fields in the `configureFormFields` but I can't access them using the above after the form has been submitted. I can see the request array but `get('page')` returns null. Also, the request array is multidimensional.

Any advice appreciated.

Simple example of what I'm trying to do is below:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)  
{  
    $formMapper  
        ->add('title')  
        ->add(  
            'subobject',  
            'hidden',  
            array(  
                'mapped' => false,  
                'data' => 'sub'  
            )  
        )  
    ;  
}  
public function prePersist($object)  
{  
    $subobject_request = $this->getRequest()->request->get('subobject');  
    print_r($subobject_request); //is null  
    die();  
}
```

Comment: Can you post a little more code?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a bit late but I hope it will be helpful for someone:

```
$this->getForm()->get('subobject')->getData()
```

Comment: at least some versions it does not work, not sure which I am having, in composer.json when I search sonata, I just find 5 bundles with this word

Answer (score 4):

Your attempt looks good. Looking at this post:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonata-users/NS0mTAAHt7o

I could successfuly use:

```
public function preUpdate($object)
{
    $uniqid = $this->getRequest()->query->get('uniqid');
    $formData = $this->getRequest()->request->get($uniqid);
    var_dump($formData);exit;
}
```

to retrieve all submitted elements.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure , but for mapped field you get the values directy in the parameter of your prepersist .

did you try to access your 'sub' values directly from $object ? like

```
$object->sub;
```

The $this->getRequest() works for symfony but i think it's a little bit different in sonata admin bundle ..

Answer (score 0):

Just an example for relation `Office > Plan` and looking for prop `Plan.nameEn`.
In `OfficeAdmin.php`:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
    $formMapper->add('plan', 'sonata_type_admin')
}

public function preUpdate($marina) {
    if ($planName = $this->getForm()->get('plan')->get('name_en')->getData()) {}
}
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: planName`